# Function $ y = x^n - nx$, where $x \geq 0$ and $n \geq 2$.

Tags: calculus

$f(x)=x^n - nx$ where $x \geq 0$ and $n \geq 2$.

[image]

Count the coloured area on the graph of the function, when n is 2, greater than 2 and goes towards infinity.

How can we mathematically prove that when n = infinity the area is equal to -infinity?

Comment: x^n or n^x? -nx or -dx? If you are looking for help, spend a little bit of time making sure your writing is correct.

Comment: Title says $x^n$, body says $n^x$.

Comment: Whether one calls the area positive or negative is a matter of convention. Usually the convention is that it is positive. Here the "top" curve is the $x$-axis and the bottom curve is $x^n-nx$. The usual calculus procedure will give area $\int_0^a (nx-x^n)\,dx$ where $a=(n-1)^{1/n}$.

Comment: I *really* don't think that the shaded area of the graph for $x^2-2x$ is under $-1,000$. We can actually figure this out ourselves. $0=x^2-2x=x(x-2)$. So the zeroes are $x=0,2$. So the area under the curve would be $-4/3$ by basic integration, a ways away from $-1,057$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=x^n-nx$$

The roots are:

$$x^n-nx=(x^{n-1}-n)x=0$$

$$x=0,\sqrt[n-1]{n}$$

The area:

$$A_n=\int_0^{\sqrt[n-1]{n}} (x^n-nx) dx = (\frac1{n+1}x^{n+1}-\frac{n}{2}x^2)|_0^{\sqrt[n-1]{n}}= \frac1{n+1}n^{(\frac{n+1}{n-1})}-\frac{n}{2}(n^{\frac{2}{n-1}})$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=-\infty$$

Comment: Hey, thank you! I just realised, the greater the n value is, the smaller the area is. I understand that when n goes infinity our area goes -infinity. But how can we mathematically prove it? Can I use infinity as a value on my n and solve the intergral and get -infinity?

Comment: The second term has higher power, so it grows faster

Comment: No, you can't use infinity as a value (at least not directly). ar2015 provided a complete computation (I left it to you - it is YOUR homework). The final result can be rearranged as $$(\frac 1 {n+1} - \frac 1 2) \times n \times n^{\frac 2 {n-1}}.$$ As $n$ goes to infinity, the first term has limit $-\dfrac 1 2$, the second has limit $+ \infty$ and the last term is $\ge 1$, so the limit is $- \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

By convention, area under the horizontal ($x$) axis is considered negative. This is consistent with the definition of area as an integral: under the horizontal axis you integrate a negative function, so the integral will be negative.

When you say you are "calculating" the results for 2 or for 10, are you calculating them, or just punching keys on a calculator? That is not "calculating."

When $n$ goes to infinity... First compute (analytically/algebraically, not on a calculator!) the result for fixed (but arbitrary) $n$; the only reasonable meaning of "what happens when $n$ goes to infinity" is to look at the sequence $A_n$ of areas and studying the limit of this expression as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: When nn goes to infinity... First compute (analytically/algebraically, not on a calculator!) the result for fixed (but arbitrary) nn; the only reasonable meaning of "what happens when nn goes to infinity" is to look at the sequence AnAn of areas and studying the limit of this expression as nn goes to infinity. I can't understand what you mean. can you please simplfy it?

Comment: I already did, in a comment to ar2015's answer.