# Area of function $x^n - nx$

Tags: calculus

$f(x)=x^n−nx$ where $x \ge 0x \ge 0$ and $n \ge 2n \ge 2$.

[image]

Determine the coloured area on the graph when $n = 2$, greater than 2 and when it goes towards infinity.

When I put $n=2$, the area should therefore be $−1,057$

When I put it for instance $n=10$ I get answer $−5.85$

are my calculations correct?

**Also, what happens when $n$ goes towards infinity, how can we make a mathematical conclusion, and how can I prove it?**

Comment: How does this differ from your previous question:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714904/function-y-xn-nx-where-x-geq-0-and-n-geq-2 ?

Comment: I redid some changes

Comment: What else did you expect?

Comment: What changes?  This looks like an exact duplicate.

Comment: I realised my calculations are correct, but I still can not fathom what value n should have when it goes towards infinity.

Comment: I don't understand.  $n$ is just a variable...it can have any value you say it can have.  By the way, for the case $n=2$ we have $x^2-2x$, yes?  So you want $\int_0^2 (x^2-2x) \;dx = -\frac 43$  which is not the number you report.

Comment: x is the variable, we are at one time given details about n = 2, but we need to investigate when it is greater than 2 and goes towards infinity

Comment: Your integral is incorrect, because the graph cuts x-axis on 0 and (n^1/n-1).

Comment: And $2^{1/1}=2$.  Indeed,   if $x^2=2x$ we have $x=0$ or $x=2$.

Comment: Yap, realised you are right. But I still cannot understand what value on n I can use when I want it to go towards infinity

Comment: sorry, I have no idea what you are asking.  The value for $n=10$ is wrong too.  Good luck!

Comment: I added a new answer. please delete this question.